# How to use Django Model computed property into a Django Manager Model?

Tags: python, django

I trying to use my django model computed property into a custom manager in order to achieve a custom result. But django is allowing just to use the normal properties into manager.

I already tried to add @property to my computed property but is not working.

This my code:

```
class Produto(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fabricante = models.ForeignKey('Fabricante', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    frete_ipi = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    cost_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)

    @property
    def real_cost_price(self):
        p = (self.cost_price * self.frete_ipi) + self.cost_price
        return round(p, 2)
```

And i'm trying to use the "real_cost_price" into my manager and is not working.

```
class EstoqueCentroManager(models.Manager):
    def total_venda(self):
        total = self.all().aggregate(valor=Sum(F('quantidade') * F('produto__real_cost_price'), output_field=FloatField()))
        return total
```

How can i use this computed property "real_cost_price" into my manager? Or there another work around to achieve this kind of result?

Thanks!

Comment: A property is *not* part of the database model, so you can *not* make ORM calls with it. Properties are a mechanism of Python, but the database does not know anything about the Python/Django layer that is built on top of the database schema.

Comment: Hey Willen, thanks for your quick answer. So what do you recomend in this case? Should i recalculate this property in my manager in order to achieve what i want?

Comment: @VinicusBarcelos: yes, you will need to add an expression like `F('cost_price') * F('frete_ipi') + F('cost_price')` instead. So "implement" the logic as a database expression so to speak.

Comment: Great! I will do it! Please post this as an answer so i can accept it! Have a nice weekend!